# "At least one object must implement IComparable" for an INT? As far as I know, it does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, icomparable

Ok, I have a simple `IEnumerable<HtmlString> things` and I want to divide it up into four equal groups.

```
var quarter = things.OrderBy(t => t.Foo).Count() / 4;
```

should do the trick, but instead I get this funkiness:

> Server Error in '/' Application. At least one object must implement
> IComparable. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: At least one object must
> implement IComparable.
>
> **Line 36:           int quarter = things.OrderBy(t => t.Foo).Count() / 4;**

Anyone know what the heck is going on here?  Why would I need to implement IComparable to get a simple count?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. My guess is that you've got lazy sorting going on...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My guess is that this is to do with lazy evaluation of LINQ's `OrderBy`. For example, if you have:

```
var things = unsortedThings.OrderBy(foo => foo.Bar);
var quarter = things.Count() / 4;
```

then if the `foo.Bar` properties can't be compared with each other, that will throw exactly that exception.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Foo {}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foos = new[] { new Foo(), new Foo() };
        var ordered = foos.OrderBy(x => x);
        Console.WriteLine(ordered.Count());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareKeys(Int32 index1, Int32 index2)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.QuickSort(Int32[] map, Int32 left, Int32 right)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Program.Main()
```

Comment: Right you are, my friend.  I removed the .OrderBy() and everything works as advertized.  Thanks again.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141891/at-least-one-object-must-implement-icomparable