# At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedSet<Player> PlayerList = new SortedSet<Player>();

            while (true)
            {
                string Input;
                Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Create new player and score.");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Display Highscores.");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Write out to XML file.");
                Console.Write("Input Number: ");
                Input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Input == "1")
                {
                    Player player = new Player();
                    string PlayerName;
                    string Score;

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("-=CREATE NEW PLAYER=-");
                    Console.Write("Player name: ");
                    PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Player score: ");
                    Score = Console.ReadLine();

                    player.Name = PlayerName;
                    player.Score = Convert.ToInt32(Score);

                    //====================================
                    //ERROR OCCURS HERE
                    //====================================
                    PlayerList.Add(player);


                    Console.WriteLine("Player \"" + player.Name + "\" with the score of \"" + player.Score + "\" has been created successfully!" );
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i keep getting the "

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

" when trying to add a second player, the first one works, but the second one doesn't.
I also MUST use `SortedSet` because that is the requirement for the work, it's school work.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you need to know - You `Player` class must implement the `IComparable` interface

Comment: This kind of error shouldn't exist, we have a nice typesafe language for a reason, `SortedSet<T>` should really have a constraint of `T : IComparable<T>`

Comment: Use `ThenBy()` instead of implementing `IComparable<>` or `IComparer<>`.

Comment: *SortedSet<T> should really have a constraint of T : IComparable<T>* -- no, because then you couldn't use an external comparer on a set of objects that don't have their own.

Comment: *Use ThenBy() instead of implementing IComparable<> or IComparer<>* -- first, you mean `OrderBy`. Second, that doesn't help ... you still need a comparer (obviously ... the system doesn't know how to order Players without being told).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Well, you're trying to use `SortedSet<>`... which means you care about the ordering. But by the sounds of it your `Player` type doesn't implement `IComparable<Player>`. So what sort order would you expect to see?

Basically, you need to tell your `Player` code how to compare one player with another. Alternatively, you could implement `IComparer<Player>` somewhere else, and pass that comparison into the constructor of `SortedSet<>` to indicate what order you want the players in. For example, you could have:

```
public class PlayerNameComparer : IComparer<Player>
{
    public int Compare(Player x, Player y)
    {
        // TODO: Handle x or y being null, or them not having names
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// Note name change to follow conventions, and also to remove the
// implication that it's a list when it's actually a set...
SortedSet<Player> players = new SortedSet<Player>(new PlayerNameComparer());
```

Comment: +1, because this is the only answer that actually explains the OP **why** he needs to implement IComparable

Comment: yupp thanks, im trying this but, im trying to compare the scores of each of the player, trying to arrange it so that the highest score goes first and so.
But im getting this Error:
Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ConsoleApplication1.Player' is less accessible than method 'ConsoleApplication1.Comp.Compare(ConsoleApplication1.Player, ConsoleApplication1.Player)

Comment: @user1930824: Right, so you need to make it an internal class rather than a public one. Then compare scores rather than names. (I'm not going to spoonfeed you the *exact* code you need...)

Comment: I never expected someone to give me the exact code i needed, however i'm very inexperienced with programming overall, so all i expect is just some small help, so thanks for helping at least.

And also I tried making them internal, then it just kept telling me that it should be returning an int value.

Comment: @user1930824: Well then it sounds like you're not returning an `int` value from your `Compare` (or `CompareTo`) method. At every step, the error message has said exactly what's wrong. Learning to read error messages carefully is a very important skill in software development.

Comment: @user1930824: Look at my example code - does it return a player? No. It returns an integer which indicates the result of the comparison (the first item should be ordered first, or the second item should be ordered first, or they're equal). You're trying to implement an interface - so read the documentation for that interface... in particular, the documentation for the `Compare` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx

Comment: I got it! Thanks a ton for the help!

Sorry about being such a beginner at this, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I voted this up to 9, and I'd like to know whether the code I've provide suitable.

Comment: Do note the subtlety in the answer that, if you are passing a comparer in the constructor, it is an IComparer with a Compare(lhs, rhs) method. But, if you want to add the interface to the Player object itself and not have to pass it on the constructor, it is the IComparable interface with a CompareTo(rhs) method. Just lost an hour on that one.

Comment: Jon, but what does it actually mean when it says "**At least one object** must implement IComparable"? At least one object of which set of objects?

Comment: @d453: At least one object within each pair-wise comparison performed. In reality, it would be very odd for only *some* of the elements to be comparable.

Comment: Is this why it's a run-time (and not compile-time) check? In case someone finds some strange way to have only some elements comparable? Or is there a real use-case that makes it worth having that check run only at run-time?

Comment: @unhammer: I don't know offhand, and getting back into the context of this is more effort than it's worth for a 7-year old question, I'm afraid.

Comment: Guess I should formulate a new Question when I find time (it bugs me that e.g. List<Foo>().Sort() compiles but fails at runtime if Foo doesn't implement IComparable)

Comment: @unhammer: Well, it would only fail if there are items that don't actually implement IComparable. You could sort a `List<object>` that actually only contained strings, for example. (I believe.)

Answer (score 18):

Sometime it raises when you forget the order property

```
SortedSet<Player> players = players.OrderBy(c => c);
```

but it must be like :

```
SortedSet<Player> players = players.OrderBy(c => c.PlayerName);
```

Comment: This is the most common mistake I see relating to this error.

Answer (score 5):

This is a more general answer to this error i suppose.

This line will fail with the error you got:

```
Items.OrderByDescending(t => t.PointXYZ);
```

However you can specify how to compare it directly:

```
Items.OrderByDescending(t => t.PointXYZ.DistanceTo(SomeOtherPoint))
```

Then you dont need the IComparable interface.
Depends on the API you are using. 
In my case i have a Point and a DistanceTo-method. (Revit API)
But an integer should be even easier to determine the "size/position" of.

Comment: Pointed me to the fact I was trying to compare to the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

You Player class needs to implement the IComparable interface..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.icomparable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your Player class must implement the IComparable interface. The SortedSet holds the items in a sorted order, but how would it know what the sorted order is if you haven't told it how to sort them (using IComparable)?

Answer (score 0):

it mostly occur if you forgot to write property, instead you used object

for example

```
options.OrderBy(o => o.Rate.Value)  --- Correct 

options.OrderBy(o => o.Rate)   ---- wrong
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your `Player` class implement `IComparable`.

Comment: show your working for people to understand thoroughly.