# Linq OrderBy Sub List

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am trying to perform a fairly simple order by but seem to be struggling on how to go about doing it. Take for instance I have these two classes.

```
public class Method
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public List<Slot> Slots { get; set; }
}

public class Slot
{
    public DateTime ExpectedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
}
```

Using the code below I want to order by the cheapest option and then by the quickest delivery date.

```
var methods = new List<Method>();

methods.Add(new Method { Id = 1, Name = "Standard", Price = 0M, Slots = new List<Slot> { new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).Date } } });
methods.Add(new Method { Id = 2, Name = "Super Fast Next Day", Price = 0M, Slots = new List<Slot> { new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date } } });

var b = methods.OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .ThenBy(y => y.Slots.OrderBy(t => t.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Date)
        .ThenBy(t => t.ExpectedDeliveryDate.TimeOfDay))
            .ToList();
```

The trouble I am getting here is that I am getting a runtime error stating "At least one object must implement IComparable".

Although I can fix this by implementing the IComparable interface, I was wondering if it was possible to do this. I imagine there is as if I had this code (see below) it works fine.

```
var slots = new List<Slot>();

slots.Add(new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).Date });
slots.Add(new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date });
slots.Add(new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).Date });
slots.Add(new Slot { ExpectedDeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.Date });

var d = slots.OrderBy(x => x.ExpectedDeliveryDate);
```

Cheers, DS.

Apologies for the naming of variables such as `xyz` in example above :) Code can be copied and pasted for manipulation pleasure.

*EDIT*
- Updated to simplify code example.
- Expectation of result would be after successful sorting

```
Input
  ID     Name            Price    Slot
  1      Standard        0        DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).Date
  2      Super Fast      0        DateTime.Now.Date

Output
  2      Super Fast      0        DateTime.Now.Date  
  1      Standard        0        DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).Date
```

So my super fast option should be top due to it being the cheapest and of course has the quickest delivery date.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect it to *mean* to order a collection of delivery methods by their slots. Can you give sample data and expected results? And why would you order by year then month then date (which doesn't mean what I think you think it means) rather than just ordering by the ExpectedDeliveryDate itself?

Comment: @DrSchizo The part that you haven't clarified yet is that each one of your Methods can have multiple slots, but your example of expected results only show one slots per method. What's the expected behavior when a Method has several slots? When it has zero slots? You need to decide what should happen in that case in order for this question to make sense.

Comment: This type of question is already answered by John: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14141926/213550

Comment: If it has multiple slots then it should pick the item with the earliest date to today. I am beginning to think the only option is to implement IComparable.. @Admin cheers for the edit, don't know how to format tables on site :)

Comment: @DrSchizo And what if there are some that have zero slots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Min()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to pick out the slot with the earliest date, like so:

```
        var query = deliveryMethods
            .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.Min(s => s.ExpectedDeliveryDate).Year)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Slots.Min(s => s.ExpectedDeliveryDate).Month)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Slots.Min(s => s.ExpectedDeliveryDate).Date)
            .ToList();
```

Or, just

```
        var query = deliveryMethods
            .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.Min(s => s.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Date))
            .ToList();
```

Do be aware that `Min()` will throw an exception when the input sequence is empty and the type being minimized is a value type.  If you want to avoid the exception, you could do this:

```
        var query2 = deliveryMethods
            .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.Min(s => (DateTime?)(s.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Date)))
            .ToList();
```

By converting the `DateTime` to a nullable, `Min()` will return a null for an empty sequence, and `Method` objects with empty slot list will get sorted to the beginning.

Comment: I must of lost my marbles, I tried that last night for some odd reason and I got an IComparable exception. However, I guess the use of "Min" is the key here :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to give an explanation of why the attempt you posted in your original post wasn't working:

```
var xyz = deliveryMethods
        .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.OrderBy(y => y.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Year))
        .ThenBy(x => x.Slots.OrderBy(y => y.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Month))
        .ThenBy(x => x.Slots.OrderBy(y => y.ExpectedDeliveryDate.Date))
        .ToList();
```

It was because you were nesting `OrderBy`s inside `OrderBy`s.

`x.Slots.OrderBy(...)` produces an `IEnumerable<Slot>`, so you were basically telling it "compare these `IEnumerable<Slot>`s against each other to decide the order of the delivery methods". But Linq doesn't know how to compare an `IEnumerable<Slot>` against another one and decide which comes before the other (`IEnumerable<Slot>` does not implement `IComparable<T>`), so you were getting an error.

The answer, as another user has pointed out, is to give it something that *can* be compared. As you have afterwards clarified, that would be the earliest slot for each delivery method:

```
var xyz = deliveryMethods
        .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.Min(y => y.ExpectedDeliveryDate))
        .ToList();
```

This will work under the assumption that each delivery method has at least one slot, but will throw a runtime exception if any of them has zero slots (or if `Slots` is null). I've asked you twice what it should do in that case, and I encourage you to clarify that.

One possible solution would be to only include delivery methods that have slots:

```
var xyz = deliveryMethods
        .Where(x => x.Slots != null && x.Slots.Any())
        .OrderBy(x => x.Slots.Min(y => y.ExpectedDeliveryDate))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Good explanation on the nesting of orderby. The side effect as you pointed out with slots not containing any items or being null is an issue but there is a solution.

Comment: @DrSchizo I provided one possible solution to the no slots/null slots issue.