# Linq order by sub-sub-collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection that starts out as XML returned from an API like this:

```
<table>
   <row id="1">
      <field id="date">2017-01-02</field>
      <field id="salary">125000</field>
   </row>
   <row id="2">
      <field id="date">2016-01-02</field>
      <field id="salary">130000</field>
   </row>
</table>
```

The XML is deserialised to typical POCOs:

```
public class Table
{
   public Row[] Rows { get;set; }
}

public class Row
{
   public Field[] Fields { get;set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Id { get;set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }
}
```

The API makes no promises regarding the order in which rows are returned, and I want to retrieve the row with the most recent date value. If the date was an actual property on a `Row` object then I could use the technique shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27686805/319980, (using the `Min` LINQ operator to sort the `Table.Rows` collection by the `Date` property) but that doesn't appear to be an option here, since date is a value on a child collection.

Assuming that the `date` field will always be present, can this be done in pure LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is order the `Rows` by the `date` and then take the first row. To order by the `date` you should parse the string:

```
var result = table.Rows.OrderByDescending(r => DateTime.ParseExact(
    r.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == "date")?.Value ?? DateTime.MinValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    "yyyy-MM-dd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault();
```

A more robust version can be to use `TryParse` for the date instead of just parsing, and in the case of failure returning `DateTime.MinValue` so row is not chosen

Comment: Much tidier than my solution, which was to use a projection to convert the Row into something that could be queried directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderByDescending` and `First` operators to obtain the result. Assuming the `date` field is always present and that it is a valid date you could write it like this:

```
table.Rows
    .OrderByDescending(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Fields.First(f => f.Id == "date").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .First();
```

If you can add the `morelinq` package, you can use the `MaxBy` operator:

```
table.Rows
    .MaxBy(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Fields.First(f => f.Id == "date").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Side note: quite strange to declare variable as _ (indicating it is unused) and then actually use it.

Comment: @Evk Yeah, sorry changed it, I sometimes use `_` when the expression  is a simple property access so as to highlight the important part, but I try to avoid doing this in public code. This one slipped :)